# Upper bound on $|\boldsymbol{A}^{-1}\boldsymbol{x}|_1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-norms

Let $\boldsymbol x=[1,0,\cdots,0]^T\in\mathbb R^{n×1}$, $ \boldsymbol A\in\mathbb R^{n×m}$ be invertible, and let $f= |\boldsymbol A^{-1}\boldsymbol x|_1$, where $|(·)|_1$ is the absolute value norm and $\boldsymbol A^{-1}$ is any generalized inverse of $\boldsymbol{A}$.

Is it now possible to find a constant $ c  $ based on the properties of  $ \boldsymbol{A }$ such that $f<c_1$?

---

I have been looking at (induced) matrix norms, where it seems I may be able to get the result based on the eigenvalues and conditioning number of $\boldsymbol{A}$, however I am not able to finalize an answer. Feel free to make any other assumptions that are necessary.

Comment: How about $c_1 = |A^{-1}|_1$?

Comment: Also, in order for $A$ to be "invertible" in the usual sense, we must have $m = n$.

Comment: Yes I think so. I would however (if possible) like to express it based on $\boldsymbol{A}$ without explicitly use of the inverse. Optimally I would like to find $c_1$ using general properties such as eigenvalues /and or condition number, etc..*

I meant the generalized inverse. Edited

Comment: If you have the condition number, then $|A^{-1}|_1 = \frac{\kappa(A)}{|A|_1}$ for the usual inverse

Comment: I am uncertain how to obtain the 1-norm condition number, so I would like to use the two-norm (i.e. $ |A^{-1}|_2 = \frac{\kappa(A)}{|A|_2 } $) . At any rate based on your comment, I think I had some progress:

 Using $ \frac{ |A^{-1}|_1}{\sqrt{n}} \le   |A^{-1}|_2$ , we apparently get $ |A^{-1}|_1 \le \frac{\kappa(A) \sqrt{n}}{|A|_2} = \frac{\kappa(A) \sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{\text{max}(\text{eig}( \boldsymbol{A}^T  \boldsymbol{A}))}}  $

Here I used 10.4.4-10.4.5 of this: https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf

Does it work out as I have outlined?